# Popup window not appearing in R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, file-io

I am trying to deploy a Shiny app via https://www.shinyapps.io, but am experiencing difficulty. **Note**: things work fine locally on my machine.

Specifically, my app calls one of my R packages and runs said package under the hood. The package prompts a user to input a FASTA file via `base::file.choose()`.

My problem is similar to the one outlined here

[Error when using file.choose() in Shiny Web App (deployed online)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58176070/error-when-using-file-choose-in-shiny-web-app-deployed-online)

Is there a simple way to solve this without having to use `shiny::fileInput()`? I don't want to have to change any of my package code.

My app is here: https://hacsim.shinyapps.io/hacsim-rshiny-app/

To reproduce the error I get, click "RUN SIMULATION", then navigate to "Sub interface" and click "Run". A pop-up window should appear. Instead the error

```
character(0)
Error: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
```

appears in the Result panel.

Any help is welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Comment: `base::file.choose` cannot work on a deployed shiny app, it is a console-only `interactive()` kind of thing. It works on your console because you are testing it in an interactive session.

Comment: You might be able to write a function and name it `file.choose` that uses shiny's mechanisms; this way, all you have to do is source one more file of code. Offhand I don't know what this function looks like, but I believe it is your only option, as using `base::file.choose` is completely out for deployments.

Comment: Hmm... I wasn't aware of this. I'll try writing the function you suggest and open a new question linking to this post should I have issues.

Comment: I think the `shinyFiles` package might do the trick.

Comment: It looks like a good package, though I wonder if the OP is looking for filesystem access to the *server* files (`shinyFiles` does this) or *client* files (not `shinyFiles`).

Comment: I am the OP. i just came across `shinyFiles` upon quickly Googling. If there's already an implementation out there, then there is no need to reinvent the wheel (I think}. I'm just now investigating the package's feasibility by running the included examples.

Comment: shinyapps.io [application only has access to the data that was uploaded with the application at the time of deployment.](https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/Storage.html#:~:text=The%20application%20only%20has%20access%20to%20the%20data%20that%20was%20uploaded%20with%20the%20application%20at%20the%20time%20of%20deployment.)